# Error while performing string copy operation in C++

Tags: c++

Please explain why is this giving an error but the other on is running fine
The following code gives the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1,s2;
    int i;

    cout << "Enter the string to copy into another string : ";
    getline(cin,s1);

    for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
      s2[i]=s1[i];
    }
    s2[i]='\0';
    cout<<"\n\nCopied String S2 is : "<<s2;
    return 0;
}
```

**Error looks like this**

[image: Error looks like this]

****But this works perfectly fine****

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s1[100], s2[100], i;

    cout << "Enter the string to copy into another string : ";
    cin>>s1;

    for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
      s2[i]=s1[i];
    }
    s2[i]='\0';
    cout<<"\n\nCopied String S2 is : "<<s2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For `std::string s2`, `s2[i]` exhibits undefined behavior when `i >= s2.size()`. Which it is in your first example, as`s2.size() == 0`

Comment: Instead of looping simply `s2 = s1;` would copy a `std::string` correctly

Comment: @UnholySheep My assignment says without using inbuilt functions please help me with another way to gain marks.

Comment: You cannot copy a `std::string` without using "inbuilt functions" - the internals of a `std::string` are not something you can just mess with, they are hidden from you (since there's a lot of optimizations going on in there).

Comment: `s2[i]` calls `std::string::operator[]`. Why is it OK to call that, but not `std::string::operator=`? What exactly is the definition of "inbuilt function", and how does it manage to distinguish between these two member functions of `std::string` class?

Comment: _My assignment says without using inbuilt functions_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `s2` is initialized to an empty string with a length of 0, so you can't write past the bounds. If you want to, you must first resize it:

```cpp
s2.resize(s1.length());
for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; ++i)
{
    s2[i]=s1[i];
}
```

Also, c++ `std::string` does not need a terminating nullbyte, unlike C strings.